# Should I use both caches pane and panels?

Tags: panels, caching

this is my first post here on SE after years and years of just using the platform for researching, I hope I do it right!

On a D7 site I use several cache systems/layers, mainly filecache, views cache, panels cache and boost.

I have good results with caching the panels only, but I recently read an article (link not at hand unfortunately) that recommended to use *both* caches, the one for the *panel* and the cache for *each pane* at the *same time*.

Does this bring me any performance gain?

Or should I either use the pane or the panels cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you panel already in cache, it doesn't matter that you panes are in cache, because cache of panel are alredy include panes.

But if you panel cache have lifetime around 1 hour and some panes have lifetime around 1 day (but not all) it can be usefull and take more performance to you.

So, cache of panels and panes for the same time doesn't take more effect then cache for panels only.